# Clearing Raphael canvas on button click

Tags: jquery, raphael, countdown

I have a combo countdown timer using Raphael circular pie-chart countdown + a digit timer, running when the button #Timer60SecStart is clicked. I am cheating a bit here, the Raphael animation is totally separate the the countdown timer, but both run for 60 seconds when called by clicking #Timer60SecStart and seem to match up OK.

My problem is that each time I call drawCircle() it adds a new circle while leaving the existing circle there, so you wind up with multiple countdown circles scattered across the page. I want a clearCircle() function that clears the previous circle before beginning to draw the new circle.

Had a look at this answer [how-to-properly-remove-a-raphael-svg-element-referenced-in-an-animated-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877585/how-to-properly-remove-a-raphael-svg-element-referenced-in-an-animated-set) but couldn't get the set/item/splice bit to work with what I'm doing.

Here's my code:

```
//Raphael Start

var archtype = Raphael("canvas", 100, 100);

function drawCircle() {
  var archtype = Raphael("canvas", 100, 100);
  archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
    var alpha = 360 / total * value,
        a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
        y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
        path;
    if (total == value) {
        path = [
            ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
            ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
        ];
    } else {
        path = [
            ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
            ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
        ];
    }
    return {
        path: path
    };
  };

  //make an arc at 50,50 with a radius of 30 that grows from 0 to 40 of 100 with a bounce
  var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
      "stroke": "#f00",
      "stroke-width": 40,
      arc: [50, 50, 0, 100, 30]
  });

  my_arc.animate({
     arc: [50, 50, 100, 100, 30]
  }, 60000);

  set.push(my_arc);
  console.log(set)

} //end drawCircle

function clearCircle() {
  alert("clear Circle");
}

// Countdown Timer Stuff
var longTimer = 0;


$('#Timer60Sec').countdown({until: longTimer, compact:true});


$('#Timer60SecStart').click(function() { 
    longTimer = new Date();
    longTimer.setSeconds(longTimer.getSeconds() + 60.5)
    $('#Timer60Sec').countdown('option',{until: longTimer});
    drawCircle();    
    clearCircle();
});
```

And here it all is as a handy JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WDpKP/2/

Assistance gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the tags that hold the arc.

```
function clearCircle() {
  $('svg').remove();
}
```

As you are writing your own `<svg>` tags you can add an `id` to them if needed and change your code to

```
function clearCircle() {
  $('svg#youridhere').remove();
}
```

This will prevent other `<svg>` tags in your page being removed as well.

Comment: Works perfectly: here is the updated JSFiddle for the future curious: http://jsfiddle.net/WDpKP/5/

Comment: This will remove all existing `svg`

Comment: I assumed the one he showed were all that was there. The solution was not meant to save the world. Downvoting on accepted answers seems a little weird to me.